# Is there a package for webhook fulfullment for DialogFlow V2?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am using `actions-on-google` npm package for my webhook server. However, that does not support DialogFlow V2.

While I can find many client libraries for V2, is there something for the server/webhook side? It seems that `actions-on-google` [does not support](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/80) V2.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [Dialogflow fulfillment-webhook-nodejs](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-nodejs) sample on GitHub. That provides a sample webhook for the v2 API.